# How to make unique combination of columns values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data like this:

```
id |  link  |  name  | date 
 1     aa      bob      1
 1     aa      tom      2
 1     bb      tom      3
 2     cc      lora     4
```

It means I can have not unique values in any column but I CAN'T have the same row with identical `id` `link` `name` (date doesn't matter). This is the example what I can't have:

```
 id |  link  |  name  |  date 
  1     aa       bob      1
  1     aa       bob      2
```

I tried to:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE KEY `uk_id_link_name` (id, link, name);
```

also:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`id`, `link`, `name`);
```

But it gives me an error:

> Duplicate entry

How to make unique rows (combination of columns values which is not unique)?

**EDIT:** I don't want to delete duplicates from table.

Comment: Add the UNIQUE constraint before inserting data?

Comment: You have to de-duplicate before you can add the unique key you seem to want.

Comment: @RaymondNijland is it possible to get what I want without deleting?

Comment: It's not clear what you do want. Are you presenting a random row for a distinct  id, link, name or are you trying to add a key for performance purposes or something else? BTW @RaymondNijland  suggested an approach , did you find that inappropriate?

Comment: "is it possible to get what I want without deleting?" Maybe with some triggers you can simulate that unique contraint (key).. But like @P.Salmon said it's not completly clear.  .. Edited "RaymondNijland suggested an approach , did you find that inappropriate?" you are taking about a view right?

Answer (score 2):

Your table already violates the unique constraint.  So you need to get rid of the offending values.

You can delete all but the earliest date:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select id, link, name, min(date) as mindate
          from t
          group by id, link, name
         ) tt
         using (id, link, name)
    where date > mindate;
```

When the data is compatible, you can add the unique constraint.

Note:  back up/make a copy of the table before doing this, so you don't lose data that you might really need.

Comment: Not unique values in columns is allowed. It's normal and wanted. My goal is to get unique rows not columns. But in your way, if I understand correct, you suggest me to get rid of duplicates in columns. That's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for SQL Server should be the next:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName UNIQUE (id, link, name)
```

But before create the constraint, of course you should ensure that there are not existing rows braking the constraint, for example using this query:

```
SELECT id, link, name, COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY id, link, name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

This query returns the duplicates grouping by the three fields: id, link, name

If the query returns rows, you have to solve these duplicates before create the unique constraint.